# Mysql Load Inline - Specific Columns

Tags: mysql

Looking for a bit more explanation from question asked here:

[User Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202564/how-to-insert-selected-columns-from-csv-file-to-mysql-using-load-data-infile)

I've looked over the doc on MySQL however I'm looking for bit simpler terms as things aren't making sense on the site.  I don't understand what:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE t1
(column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3, ...)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`
```

the @dummy's are for?

If i have columns a,b,c and data for those how would I insert it limiting only those?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in case the data in your CSV contains say 5 columns but you only want to use 3 of them for instance -- you use `@dummy` to specify that the column won't be in fact written into the table.

Comment: so by specifying column1, @dummy it won't write to it?

Comment: what it actually does it assigns the second column (after column1) to a variable called dummy -- rather than assign it to a column called dummy (which might not exist in your table). And by assigning it to a variable you are not going to use you effectively skip it.

Comment: No, imagine the data in your file has 5 columns : A,B,C,D,E -- and you are loading data into a table with 3 columns: column1, column2, column3 but you want column A from file written into the table in column1, column C into column2, and column E into column 3 -- so you won't use B and D. In that case you specify INTO TABLE t1( column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3) - so you assign column B to a dummy variable and same for column D thus skipping them.