# Inserting only the specific column from the csv using load data local file

Tags: php, sql, csv

I'm using mysql LoadDataLocalFile to enter the data from my csv file to my db. My query works when I don't have to choose any columns but this time I have to.

Suppose I have this content in my csv:

```
move_doc_number |   sku |   slot_code | qty|    store_id |  so_no | date
210               900496    PCK00001    2         20        10472   140509
```

At the above csv, the only column I want to be inserted in my table is the `so_no and move_doc_number`.

And these is my table structure

```
move_doc_number | so_no
```

This is my command in loading the csv to my db

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$this->pdo->quote($csv_dir)." 
                    IGNORE 
                    INTO TABLE `$table`
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$this->pdo->quote($this->fieldSeparator)."
                    LINES TERMINATED BY ".$this->pdo->quote($this->lineSeparator) . " " .$columns;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please refer [**`this`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202564/how-to-insert-selected-columns-from-csv-file-to-mysql-using-load-data-infile#answer-4202733)

Comment: hi, thanks for the reference. I got it working ^_^.