# How to split columns and add to mysql table from csv

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have csv file Studies contains

```
RollNo, subject1, subject2, subject3
```

Now I want to create table Study in Mysql contains column:

```
RollNo Subject
```

Eg.- csv file has entry

```
15CS1001, NLP, IR, ML
```

and corresponding entries in table would be

```
15CS1001 NLP
15CS1001 IR
15CS1001 ML
```

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202564/how-to-insert-selected-columns-from-csv-file-to-mysql-using-load-data-infile) shows how to insert selected columns from csv file to mysql, but it insert whole column.

Comment: You should consider doing the spliting in your application end and then insert the data to your table.

Comment: But if you do dump it into a temporary table then SELECT a,b UNION SELECT a, c UNION SELECT a, d will help

Comment: @Strawberry this query returns only result of first SELECT a,b

Comment: @Strawberry the result return by SELECT, is it possible to store it in table.