# Can I selectively import data from a text file into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, syntax, import

I have a 13gb .txt file which I am importing into MySQL, however I don't want to import all of the data.  For example there are many columns that are either completely empty or contain irrelevant information - I only want to import ~100/360 I've been provided. If I only create headers for the columns I want, can I select the specific corresponding data from the .txt file to be uploaded?

Normally I would use a text editor to remove the superfluous data, but I do not possess a text editor that can handle a file of this size.

Comment: show a sample which lines ok and which not. then you can filter it with grep,awk or sed and direct import this filtered data

Comment: Refer the second answer of the [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202564/how-to-insert-selected-columns-from-a-csv-file-to-a-mysql-database-using-load-da)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore specific columns in the input file by assigning them to a user-defined variable instead of a database column.

For example if you had a CSV file with 4 columns and just wanted to import columns 1 and 4 into your table you could do something like this:

```
load data infile '/tmp/so42140337.csv'
into table so42140337
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
(c1,@dummy,@dummy,c2);
```

Given the size of your input file it may be more efficient to import it in chunks rather than importing the entire file in one command. You can use the [`pt-fifo-split`](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-fifo-split.html) tool for this, following the pattern in this [blog post](http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/12/12/loading-large-flat-files-into-mysql-with-load-data-infile-and-pt-fifo-split/).