# LOAD DATA INFILE REPLACE with specific columns

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, csv

I am currently using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` successfully, and typically with `REPLACE`.  However, I am now trying to use the same command to load a CSV file into a table but only replace specific columns.

For example, table currently looks like:

```
ID    date        num1    num2
01    1/1/2017    100     200
01    1/2/2017    101     201
01    1/3/2017    102     202
```

where `ID` and `date` are the primary keys.

I have a similar CSV, but one that only has `ID, date, num1` as columns.  I want to load that new CSV into the table, but maintain whatever is in `num2`.

My current code per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202564/how-to-insert-selected-columns-from-a-csv-file-to-a-mysql-database-using-load-da):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE mycsv.csv
REPLACE INTO TABLE mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(ID, date, num1)
```

Again, my code works flawlessly when I'm replacing all the columns, but when I try to replace only select columns, it fills the other columns with NULL values.  The similar posts (like the one I referenced) haven't helped.

I don't know if this is python specific issue, but I'm using `MySQLdb` to connect to the database and I'm familiar with the `local_infile` parameter and that's all working well.  MySQL version 5.6.33.

Comment: Did you solve it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Simply load csv table into a similarly structured temp table and then run `UPDATE JOIN`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytemptable AS SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1;          --- RUN ONLY ONCE

DELETE FROM mytemptable;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE mycsv.csv
INTO TABLE mytemptable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(ID, date, num1);

UPDATE mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytemptable t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.`date` = t2.`date`
SET t1.num1 = t2.num1;
```

Comment: do we have any other options to achieve the same without using a temp table? Is there is any way we can provide specific fields to be replaced in the load data query itself?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. `LOAD DATA` *appends* data and does not *update* data and additionally CSV is not a table that can be queried. Remember the S in SQL: structured. Or in other words, SQL is run on structured data.