# How to import some columns of csv file to mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4202733/11625619) but I don't know where is the `file.csv`  located, that has been targeted in answer.

I have a `csv` file having `5Gb` of size,meaning a lot data, I want to import some of the columns from that `csv` file into my `live` database `(phpmyadmin)`.

**Note**

The `csv` file from where I want to import `some columns` is on my local computer, and I want to import about `10` columns among `30` columns.

How can I do that, please help me, thanks ?

Comment: what should I write instead of `'/tmp/mydata.txt'`, as I have question about that !

Comment: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE `/tmp/mydata.txt` , should I write the same ? also I want to import some of the columns , how can I do that ? @HimanshuAhuja

Comment: You mean to say you dont know where the file is located yes write the same

Comment: the file is located on my `local` computer, I want to upload it to the `live` database

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja , that didn't solved my problem as that is different than mine,