# MYSQL syntax errorm in sql string in java

Tags: java, mysql

Here's a code that runs perfectly in mysql command line however when I try to execute the query in java it give a syntax error not sure what's wrong.

I've added spaces and revised the code already, still not finding the solution.

```
String path = selectedfile.getAbsolutePath();
String sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + path + "' REPLACE INTO TABLE 
temp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '" + '"' + " LINES TERMINATED BY 
'\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES \n" + " 
(fname,lname,email,idemployee,statu,@hiredate,idsupervisor,
jobtitle,description,country,site,clockid) "+ 
"SET hiredate = STR_TO_DATE(@hiredate, '%m/%d/%Y');";
```

Here's the output in java

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' IGNORE 1 LINES 
>   (fname,lname,email,idemployee,statu,@hiredate,idsupervisor,job' at line 2

Comment: are the field name column names are correct  - statu   -  @hiredate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert selected columns from a CSV file to a MySQL database using LOAD DATA INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202564/how-to-insert-selected-columns-from-a-csv-file-to-a-mysql-database-using-load-da)

Comment: @zod Wrong column names wouldn't cause a syntax error.

Comment: @zod yes they're correct as status is a reserved word a replaced the column for statu and hiredate it's because I manipulate string to date when importing from csv

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the backslashes in the query, so they'll be passed through from Java to MySQL.

You're also missing a `'` around the `ENCLOSED BY` setting. Instead of concatenating strings there, you can just escape the double quote.

```
String sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + path + "' REPLACE INTO TABLE 
temp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY 
'\\r\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES \n" + " 
(fname,lname,email,idemployee,statu,@hiredate,idsupervisor,
jobtitle,description,country,site,clockid) "+ 
"SET hiredate = STR_TO_DATE(@hiredate, '%m/%d/%Y');";
```

Comment: It give this error message @Barmar:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer, but I don't think it allows you to wrap strings like this, so your code shouldn't even be compiling in the first place. Can you post the actual code, without putting line breaks into the string?

Comment: Here's the code I use in mysql:
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE temp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(fname,lname,email,idemployee,statu,@hiredate,idsupervisor,jobtitle,description,country,site,clockid)
SET hiredate = STR_TO_DATE(@hiredate, '%m/%d/%Y');
and this code runs perfectly on MYSQL command line

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I managed to get the code running here's the code that works as an example for future cases:

```
String sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + path + "' REPLACE INTO TABLE temp
\n FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' \n ENCLOSED BY '" + '"' + "' \n LINES TERMINATED 
BY '\\r\\n' \n 
IGNORE 1 LINES \n" +
" (fname,lname,email,idemployee,statu,@hiredate,idsupervisor,
jobtitle,description,country,site,clockid) \n"+
"SET hiredate = STR_TO_DATE(@hiredate, '%m/%d/%Y');";
```

Comment: Could you explain the fix so we don't have to hunt for the difference?

Comment: The only difference I can see is the placement of `\n` in the string, but that shouldn't make any difference -- MySQL doesn't distinguish between spaces and newlines as whitespace.

Comment: @Barmar The only difference I notice is the addition of a `'` to finish enclosing `ENCLOSED BY '"' `; the originally posted version would have been equivalent to `ENCLOSED BY '"andstuff' 'IGNORE 1 ....`

Comment: Seems like it would have been easier to write `ENCLOSED BY '\"'` instead of using that confusing concatenation.

Comment: So it seems that the mysql java driver works by creating the statement exactly as it is in mysql. I've added the \n to the lines where should add an enter and added an extra backslash to LINES TERMINATED BY