# How to specify column names when loading data to mySQL table?

Tags: mysql, csv, text, load

How should I specify the columns names when I want to **load a `MySQL` table** from a local .csv file using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL FILE` command in `MySQL`?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this, since the other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202564/how-to-insert-selected-columns-from-a-csv-file-to-a-mysql-database-using-load-da has no accepted answer and an incorrect answer before the correct one.  Close again if you disagree.

Comment: @ysth having an accepted answer is **not** a criterion for a dupe target and the most upvoted answer is a correct answer, altgough other answers there also work. Your answer is just a repeat of what's already there, confirming that is indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify a comma seperated list of columns, in parentheses, at the end (but before the optional SET parameters).

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-column-list

Comment: My input is a .CSV file with the first line listing column names. Then why do I need to specify it twice?

Comment: That's how it works.  You need to specify the columns in the SQL and use the IGNORE parameter to have it skip the first line