How can I update a CSV file to match the column count in MySQL table?
I have CSV files that I'm trying to upload into MySQL tables.
The CSV files have 8 columns, whereas the database table has 11.
Here is how the CSV data looks:
list_id,key,last_sent,last_open,last_click,last_unsubscribe,status,created
52480,d@email.net,,,,,active,2018-06-19 16:30:13
52480,a@aol.com,,,,,active,2021-06-05 21:45:00.8515
52480,m@yahoo.com,,,,,active,2018-06-19 16:30:26

I built the database table to match the above columns, but I have an additional 3 columns after the "created" column that are necessary.
Is there a way to update the CSV to include an additional 3 columns?
Or would it be better to just remove the 3 columns, upload the CSV, then add the 3 columns to the table after the upload?

Have a look at this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202564/how-to-insert-selected-columns-from-a-csv-file-to-a-mysql-database-using-load-da ... you don't need to tweak the CSV, if you adress the colums directly.

@Bjoern - Can LOAD DATA INFILE connect to an online server host?

it can be used tapping into streams too, but it way easier to use a file.

@JohnBeasley You can use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to send a local file to a remote DB server.
